# What does the abbreviation "B. Mon" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations, academia

I was reading a review of an urban fantasy book *Broken Homes* by Ben Aaronovitch, and one of the characters was described as:

> "Professor Harold Postmartin, a Doctor of Philosophy (PhD), a Fellow of the Royal Society (FRS), **and B.Mon**, is the Folly’s chief (and only) archivist."

What does "B. Mon" mean? Seems to be some kind of a degree, but I haven't ever heard that abbreviation before. Google was unhelpful.

Comment: For reference here is a link to original text where the review is picking up the acronym https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HxBPGyDOv00C&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=Professor+Harold+Postmartin,+a+Doctor+of+Philosophy&source=bl&ots=7VI9jOg8Ml&sig=Bsob5PE-rV43fFteDz9vCj7zp3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiso4WKgbHRAhUBfhoKHWwsDAEQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=B%20Mon&f=false

Comment: From that link I see the character is at least when introduced to the plot giving consultancy on an old German grimoire (a book of magic spells and invocations) ... which may or not be relevant to the *B.Mon* !

Comment: If a degree, it would likely by bachelors of something, thought I can't identify Mon. Interesting though that there is not artticle

Comment: Considering that the work that this sentence comes from is about a magical world, and the character described is an archivist at a branch of the police devoted to magical crimes, it could be anything at all. Bachelor of Monsters, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author [Ben Aaronovitch](https://twitter.com/Ben_Aaronovitch) kindly replied via a [Tweet](https://twitter.com/Ben_Aaronovitch/status/818136611934392325) :

[image]

Comment: Nice going straight to the source. Except this doesn't actually provide an answer, just progress. It's a Pratchett reference to ... what?

Comment: @Mitch Yep, this answer is indeed  "work-in-progress" and not a "done deal". Maybe Bachelor of Mon Repos, (Quirmian for "My Place of Rest") in Discworld?!? But as that's just a guess, I've sent him a followup tweet for clarification ... hopefully he'll reply again.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find is  [BMon, Bulletin monumental](http://www.sf-archeologie.net/-Bulletin-monumental-.html), a journal of the French Society for Archeology, for amateurs and passionates. Mentions for instance in Encyclopedia of the History of Classical Archaeology 
By Nancy Thomson de Grummond:

[image: BMON]

Would a subscription to such a journal denote a certain personality trait, in complement to the D. Phil. and F. R. S. mentions?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't stand for anything. Given the author's reply to the OP, the reference is to the Unseen University's Burser, "Professor A.A. Dinwiddie, DM (7th), D.Thau., B.Occ., M.Coll." These are all made up abbreviations, suggestive of academic honors that don't actually exist outside Discworld.

Comment: *D.Thau.* - Doctor of Thaumaturgy; *B.Occ.* - Bachelor of the Occult.

Comment: @Greybeard — Hail Eris! According to the Comedy Rule of Threes, the 'M.Coll' is more absurd by following two seemingly intelligible terms. Also, since (according to _The Light Fantastic_) the Bursar is not a wizard, 'D.Thau' would presumably be a doctorate in Thaumatology, not Thaumaturgy. ;-)